# gmock-more-args library failing to compile with latest gmock1.10.0 and vs2019

Tags: googlemock

We used `gmock-more-args` to mock few methods with more than 10 args and it was working fine. Recently we moved the `gtest/gmock` to 1.10.0 from 1.7 and also built env. to vs2019 and now we see compiler errors as below when I tried the sample code provided with the `gmock-more-args` library.
Anyone else facing this issue and found any quick fix? Is there latest version of `gmock-more-args` available?

```py
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   Project2    C:\Project\Trial\samplegmocktest\Project2\Source.cpp    15  
Error   C3646   'someMethod11': unknown override specifier  Project2    C:\Project\Trial\samplegmocktest\Project2\Source.cpp    15  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Project2    C:\Project\Trial\samplegmocktest\Project2\Source.cpp    15  
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   Project2    C:\Project\Trial\samplegmocktest\Project2\Source.cpp    15
```

Answer (score 0):

Today i found that gmock now supports a generic MOCK_METHOD which supports more than 10 params too - more details in this link: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md
so we need not depend on gmock-more-args library.